# Is there a spray directive to ignore tail slash?

Tags: scala, routes, directive, spray

What path directive selects both `http://localhost:8080/test` and `http://localhost:8080/test/`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pathEndOrSingleSlash` after `pathPrefix`, or you can do it "by hand" with an optional part of the path.